# Proof of a generic limit with log and exponential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I prove that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log_a n}{n^b}=0$

Comment: Hint: Note that log is a concave down function (1st derivative is decreasing), whereas exponential is concave up (1st derivative increasing). This implies that the denominator will eventually, necessarily, outgrow the numerator. Therefore the limit must be $0$. (Why?)

Comment: It must be $\;b>0\;$ , otherwise the result is false (and, of course, $\;1\neq a>0\;$ ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for $b>0$ the corresponding limit in $\mathbb{R}$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a x}{x^b}$$

For $a>1$ set $x=a^y \to +\infty$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a x}{x^b}=\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a a^y}{a^{by}}=\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac{y}{a^{by}}=0$$

indeed $\exists y_M$ such that $\forall y\ge y_M$

$$a^{by}\geq y^2$$

and then

$$\frac{y}{a^{by}}\le\frac{y}{y^2}=\frac1y\to0$$

For $0<a<1$ set $c=\frac1a$ and $x=\left(\frac1a\right)^y=c^y \to +\infty$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a x}{x^b}=\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac{y\log_a \frac1a}{c^{by}}=\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac{-y}{c^{by}}=0$$

Thus

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a x}{x^b}=0 \implies \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\log_a n}{n^b}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a>1$, you could substitute $n=a^t$ and the limit becomes

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t}{a^{bt}}.$$

If $0<a<1$, use $n=a^{-t}.$  Now use L'hospital (or series) if that's allowed, or perhaps a concavity argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the limit non-generic by setting $n=\sqrt[b]m$ so that

$$\frac{\log_a n}{n^b}=\frac1{b\log a}\frac{\log m}m$$ and the constants can be factored out. This is undefined when $b=0$ or $a\le0$ or $a=1$.

For $b<0$, the limit relates to $m\to0^+$ and does not exist ($\color{red}{\pm\infty}$ depending on the sign of $\log a$ if you prefer).

And for $b>0$, it is $\color{red}0$, because  by the *ratio test* with $m=e^k$,

$$\frac{\dfrac{\log e^{k+1}}{e^{k+1}}}{\dfrac{\log e^k}{e^k}}=\frac{k+1}{ek}<1.$$

---

These results extend to the case of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\log_an)^c}{n^b},$$ as it can be written

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\log_an}{n^{b/c}}\right)^c$$ and is the $c^{th}$ power of the previous limit with $b\to b/c$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\log_{a} n=\log n/\log a$ so it is sufficient to prove that $n^{-b} \log n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Next note that $b>0$ and hence $n^b\to\infty$. And $n^{-b} \log n=(1/b)n^{-b} \log n^{b} $ therefore it is sufficient to prove that $(\log x) /x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ where $x$ is a real variable.

Next we can use the defining inequality satisfied by $\log x$ given below $$\log x\leq x-1<x$$ and replacing $x$ by $\sqrt{x} $ we get $$\log x<2\sqrt{x}$$ Thus if $x>1$ then $$0<\log x<2\sqrt{x}$$ or $$0<\frac {\log x} {x} <\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$$ and applying Squeeze Theorem we get the desired result $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x} {x} =0$$

If one carefully notes the above proof, it will be clear that only two properties of the logarithm function have been used here:

- $\log(xy) =\log x+\log y,\, x,y>0$
- $\log x\leq x-1,\, x>0$

These two properties characterize the logarithm function uniquely and all the other properties of logarithm function can be derived using these properties.

Answer (score -1):

Just change basis to basis $\;e\;$ , say (and assume $\;b>0\;$, as commented):

$$\frac{\log_an}{n^b}=\frac{\frac{\log n}{\log b}}{e^{b\log n}}=\frac{\log n}{\log b\cdot\left(e^b\right)^{\log n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$